# Windows console unable to install Python packages using pip after installing SQL Server 2019 on Windows

Tags: python, sql-server, pip

I am trying to install sqlmlutils for machine learning to help manage my python packages within Microsoft Machine Learning Services and I recently upgraded to SQL Server 2019. The install fails with this error:

> Ssl module in Python is not available.

This is a known issue. See: #7 in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/known-issues-for-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15

> "After installing SQL Server 2019 on Windows, attempting to install a
>   python package via pip from a DOS command line will fail. For example:
>   pip install quantfolio This will return the following error: pip is
>   configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module
>   in Python is not available."

I tried the Workaround, which suggests the following:

> Copy the following files: libssl-1_1-x64.dll libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
>   from the folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Library\bin to the folder
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\DLLs

Then rebooted, verified the copied files were in both locations, but still I get the same error.
Does anyone know if there is a workaround that actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing OpenSSL for windows

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick. Very much appreciated.  I followed the instructions here and got the light version of OpenSSL for Windows.  tecadmin.net/install-openssl-on-windows/